# SharePoint 2013 June 2019 CU updates build number

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, update, patching

I just updated to the June 2019 CU (build no 15.0.5145.1000) onto our SharePoint 2013 test environment.

All went well and the upgrade completed successfully without any issues.

But when checking 'Servers in the Farm' from Central Admin the Configuration database version is shown as `15.0.15131.100` rather than `15.0.5145.1000`.

Is anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The Configuration database version 15.0.15131.100 only indicate the version of configuration database. If you goto CA -> Application Management -> Manage content database, and click into each content DB, you will find each of them have a schema version too.

You can check your upgrade status by CA -> Upgrade and Migration -> Check product and patch installation status. If there is no outstanding item, you are good.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the clarification, everything is fine under the installation status so after testing we'll be good to go for Production installation.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior in SharePoint 2013. Not all CUs include database schema changes and even if they include them the version number for these schema changes might be slightly smaller than the highest build number included in the patch.

Do not trust the version number that is shown in the Manage Servers section. Instead head over to the Upgrade and Migration ->Check Product and Installation Status.

Read this article for more:

https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2016/08/23/sharepoint-does-not-have-a-build-version-full-stop/